# Two ValidationSummary in the same page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validationsummary

I have two forms on the page and every form has its own `ValidationSummary`. The problem is that then server side validation is executed for `one form` the `both ValidationSummary` display validation messages. Is it possible to have two `ValidationSummary` on the same page and execute `ValidationSummary` for every form to which it is assigned?

Answer (score 0):

pass it over the public class which validation summary you want to give on the second page and set your **validation group** name with the same names.

Comment: ValidationGroup is available in ASP.NET and not in MVC.

Comment: oh..sorry!! now, kindly check @zdrsh link !